# Ambiguous tag [msf]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

When looking at a question about the Microsoft Solution Framework, I encountered [msf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msf), which is used on some different subjects of which some don't have their own tag (yet?). Microsoft Solver Foundation, Microsoft Sync Framework, Metasploit Framework, a Mozilla Thunderbird file extension, something to do with proteomes and more... Is it possible to remove/block this tag, or should we completely disambiguate it?

Comment: Note: [tag:msf] currently has 27 questions, 2 of which have it as the only tag.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

IMHO; disambiguate it and burn it now before it becomes a major problem.

It's just starting to exist and already has no coherence. Since it doesn't mean anything you can't be an expert in it.

Comment: In this case (<50 questions), the simplified burnination from here can probably be used:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination. Going by the book, we need +20 score then we can just go ahead and clean it up. Indeed I don't think we'll find any "experts" on the topic, so anyone with full edit privileges will do.

Comment: All questions are now gone.

Comment: "It's just starting to exist" as a problem.  That's surprising.  That's an old technology.  From the Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Solutions_Framework), the first release was in 1993, and the most recent was in 2005.  It was a thing in the early 2000s.  I haven't heard anything about it in over a decade

Comment: @Flydog57: It refers to the tag not any particular technology.